# Use CSS margins and padding for positioning text at the top right of a page

Tags: css, css-float

I've been asked to change my CSS for adding text to the top right of the screen on my website to use margins and padding instead of what I currently have.  The CSS I currently have for doing so is thus:

```
<style>
.text-align-top-right{
position: absolute;
top: 10px;
right: 10px;
}
</style>

<div class="text-align-top-right">Some text to align top right</div>
```

How do I do the same thing above using margins and padding?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please give some of your code for reference..

Comment: just add a div, and give it a class. @imGaurav !

Comment: code added for reference.  I'm looking for suggestions related to the CSS, not div.

Comment: Why are you being asked not to use the correct CSS for what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a rather bizarre request and certainly not the way I would recommend positioning an element however if this is some kind of test one way to do this is with **css calc**ulations.

Determine the width of the screen and then adjust the offset by the size of the div being positioned.

You will need to know the width and height of the element being positioned in this scenario.

```css
.text-align-top-right{
  margin-left:calc(100% - 110px);
  margin-bottom:calc(100% - 110px);
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  background:#b00;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-align-top-right">TOP RIGHT</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have used `<div style="text-align-top-right">Some text to align top right</div>` which is not correct. You should replace `class` attribute in place of `style` attribute and then you change margins and paddings accordingly to get the required result.

Changes made in HTML

```
<div class="text-align-top-right">Some text to align top right</div>
```

Changes made in CSS:

```
.text-align-top-right{
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   right: 0;
   margin-top: 30px;
   margin-right: 30px;
}
```

And here is the working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/MasoomS/19Ly9f9t/

Comment: @fuzzyanalysis if you want to fix it to the top right of the screen, you can replace `position: absolute;` with `position: fixed;` in the class `.text-align-top-right`

Answer (score 0):

you can do it very simple way with below CSS, you create simple DIV and add CSS to it. Check below code :

```
#topRightDisplay{
    position: relative;
}
#topRightDisplay p{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}

<div id="topRightDisplay">
    <p>some text...</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not supposed to use the position, top or right css styles.